# Nelmio install package error symfony 6 php 8.1

Tags: symfony, nelmioapidocbundle

```
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!
!!  In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 88:
!!                                                                                                                                                                   
!!    The service "nelmio_api_doc.model_describers.object" has a dependency on a non-existent service "annotations.reader". Did you mean this: "annotation_reader"?  
!!                                                                                                                                                                   
!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

I tried downgrading to version 3 and the error disappeared.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/issues/2064) may be of help to you.